# Executing dusk tests with paratest

Tags: phpunit, laravel-dusk

I want to run my dusk tests with paratest 
But here is some troubles
I have only one database
I have only one application
How can I run my tests with 
docker-compose exec app vendor/bin/paratest -p4 tests/Browser/
and get 4 instances of my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You would have to start your Docker environment 4 times to do that and paratest does not know (nor care) about your environment.

The usual way to test databases is to create individual databases per `TEST_TOKEN` or `UNIQUE_TEST_TOKEN` (see https://github.com/paratestphp/paratest#test-token ). So if your database name is "foo", than your tests need to be smart enough to

- recognize if a `TEST_TOKEN` exists (`getenv("TEST_TOKEN")`)
- create a new database "on the fly", e.g. `foo_1`
- switch the database default connection from `foo` to `foo_1` so that you application code now uses the "new" database

I've found this to be the cleanest (well, actually the only) way to get parallel test execution to work with tests that hit the database. And frankly (depending on your application) this might require a rethinking / refactoring of your current code base.

https://timacdonald.me/my-feature-test-suite-setup/ might give you some more ideas.